# Export multiple variables in TypeScript to give CommonJS equivalent

Tags: javascript, typescript

What would be the TypeScript equivalent to this CommonJS file in ES6

```
const Parser = require('./src/parser');
const numerics = require('./src/numerics');

module.exports = Parser;
module.exports.numerics = numerics
```

I have tried doing many different ways, and this is the closest I have gotten:

```
import Parser = require('./src/parser');
import numerics = require('./src/numerics');

export = Parser
```

Now, the problem with this is, it doesn't allow me to export anything else in the TypeScript fashion.

If I add this piece of code, everything works exactly like it should and is equivalent to the original JS code.

`module.exports.numerics = numerics;`

Comment: I am using tsc. And i have seen this syntax being used elsewhere too

Comment: It's incorrect ES2015. From the TypeScript documentation, it looks like [TypeScript adds it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can combine the value meanings of the two modules this way:

```
import Parser = require('./src/parser');
import numerics = require('./src/numerics');

const combined = Object.assign(Parser, {numerics});
export = combined;
```

However, any types are lost.

**Option 2:** Since `module.exports.numerics = numerics` is actually mutating the `Parser` module, it would be correct to just add a declaration of `numerics` to that module, and then write:

```
import Parser = require('./src/parser');
import numerics = require('./src/numerics');

Parser.numerics = numerics;
export = Parser;
```

You can modify the original module declaration, or depending on how the declaration is written, you may be able to add `numerics` via [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

If all the code is under your control, maybe you should just assign `numerics` as part of the `parser` module rather than using either of these strange workarounds.